# Null Pointer if sObjectType isn't Case

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer, sobjecttype

I have the apex trigger below that is meant to check the WhatId on a new Task if the WhatId belongs to a case. The trigger then populates fields on the related Case for ActivityDate and Task Type. This works as intended so long as the trigger encounters a task related to only a Case. If the Task is related to a Lead, I receive a null pointer exception on line 6, which is where I check for the sObjectType of the WhatId. Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!

```
trigger taskToCaseService on Task (after insert) {

    Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    for(Task t: Trigger.new) {
        If(t.whatId.getsObjectType() == Case.sObjectType){
            caseIdSet.add(t.whatId);
        }       
    }

    if(!caseIdSet.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>([Select Id, Task_Date_Time__c, Scheduled_Task_Type__c from Case where Id =: caseIdSet]);
        for(Task t: Trigger.new) {
            If(t.whatId.getsObjectType() == Case.sObjectType){
                Case c = caseMap.get(t.whatId);
                if(c != null) {
                    c.Scheduled_Task_Type__c = t.Type;
                    c.Task_Date_Time__c = t.ActivityDate;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!caseMap.isEmpty())
            update caseMap.values();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily handle this you just need to put a **null check.** It is used to make sure that whatId is not null.

```
for(Task t: Trigger.new) {
        If(t.whatId != null && t.whatId.getsObjectType() == Case.sObjectType){
            caseIdSet.add(t.whatId);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Tushar, 

Nailed it! That totally slipped my mind. Thank you!